# Problems with RelativeLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Java and Android and I am facing this problem:

I would like to add a photo to the top/left corner of a Rectangle. However, the `ImageView` of my photo gets always more space and so, it creates a blank space on top that I would not like to have. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The code of my Layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:padding="25dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_frame" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/foto_facebook_juan_mejorada" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's because your image size is smaller than that dimension. and you have given wrap_content. set width as match_parent and give the `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Set adjustViewBounds to true. This was the right answer! You gave it to me right? Set adjustViewBounds to true.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of 
 size of the image. If the image not fit in the space given it will add blank space.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="30dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_frame" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/foto_facebook_juan_mejorada" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```